# Flattening Multi-Index Column with Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

**I have a multi-index column dataframe that also has date. I would like the columns to be as rows.**

**For example:**

| A | A | B | B |

| X | Y | X | Y | Date   |

---

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | May-08 |

**And I need it to be**

| Start | End | Value | Date   |

---

|   A   |  X  |   1   | May-08 |

|   A   |  Y  |   2   | May-08 |

etc.

**Sorry for the wonky formatting. When I tried to add code, the submission form freaked out and I couldn't figure out how to make it work.**

**Please let me know if you have any questions and I will answer them to the best of my ability**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,'May-08']],
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                      ('A', 'X'), ('A', 'Y'),
                      ('B', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'),
                      (None, 'Date')
                  ]))

#    A     B        NaN
#    X  Y  X  Y    Date
# 0  1  2  3  4  May-08
```

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with a bit of pre-processing of the MultiIndex to remove NaNs/None (that don't `melt` well), and post-processing of the resulting Index to remove the tuple:

```
# only necessary if you have None/NaN in the MultiIndex
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.to_frame().fillna(''))

out = (df.melt([('', 'Date')], var_name=['Start', 'End'], value_name='Value')
         .rename(columns={('', 'Date'): 'Date'})
      )
```

*If the empty levels in the MultiIndex are `''`, you can skip the pre-processing.*

Output:

```
     Date Start End  Value
0  May-08     A   X      1
1  May-08     A   Y      2
2  May-08     B   X      3
3  May-08     B   Y      4
```